# Match the end of the string in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

i am new to Sphinx, that's why I need a little help,
Is it possible to search only those strings whose end matches to what is passed in the parameter?
For example we have this strings in db: "12345678", "123456788" and "324233423" and we need to find strings that end with "5678", it will be "12345678".

Answer (score 0):

Do need to enable 'infix' matching to match part words, with `min_infix_len`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len

... can then use `*` as a wildcard

```
... WHERE MATCH('*5678')
```